# How do i reset my SQLite password?

Tags: sqlite, password-recovery

I recently installed SQLite but then I forgot my password, I don't need to get the database back I just need to reset the password (or reconfigure).

Forgot to say, I don't want to bruteforce or anything else (i think it's illegal anyways).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sqlite itself does not have support for passwords. Are you using an extension and if so, which one?

Comment: i don't have any idea, i think it just asked me for password when i was trying to install it (i'm sure it's the official one anyways) i am new to all this database stuff too anyways

Comment: wait, i remember i installed the user authentication extension. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the database, you can just delete it and create a new one. So far as I understand it, the [user authentication extension](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt) is implemented per-database

Just rename (or delete if you're super-confident) the database file, and run `sqlite <database>` to create it anew